# YARN RM not releasing the resources

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, executor

I'm running spark with yarn as Resource Manager(RM). I'm submitting the application with max attempts 2 i.e. `spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=2`.One of the application is processing around 3 TB of data, because of memory issues, attempt1 failed(after processing 5 tables out of 10 tables) and attempt 2 started. Even though attempt1 failed YARN is not releasing the resources(executors) to use the same for attempt 2. Not understanding why YARN not releasing the resources. Below is the conf.

```
spark.executor.memory=30G
spark.executor.cores=5
spark.executor.instances=95
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=8G
```

Total number executors available are 100 out of which I'm trying to use 95, attempt 1 trying to use all the 95 executors. After attempt 1 failed, attempt 2 started with 5 executors. As per my understanding attempt 2 should start with 95 executors like attempt 1 as attempt 1 failed and all the resources should be available for attempt 2.

Comment: it depends on what kind of business logic you have inside executor .. did you launched any daemon threads inside executor? i would suggest repartition data and keep spark.executor.cores=2 or spark.executor.cores=4 and tune other parameters accordingly. spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead Is also too high again I'm making all assumptions here ... please update your question and add more specific details.

Comment: @kavetiraviteja, as per EMR latest suggestions 18% is the default memory overhead based on that 6GB will be good enough, however I observed memory overhead issues, so went to 8GB. I believe 5 cores won't cause any I/O issues, any specific reason for asking 2 or 4 cores? Number of partitions is 2048. I'm not running any demon services inside executors. Executing SQL queries, that's all I'm doing.